# Inaccurate data using CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I am developing an ios app which uses location services. I get the latitude & longitude data using CLLocationManager. When i analyzed the data, I found that it is not the exact location i went. Rather than road coordinates it sometimes returns me the nearby building coordinates. Lat/long values are long integers, a little bit of number change changes the location. That  creates an issue in my app. why is it happening? How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, when you retrieve the GPS coordinates also check their precision in order to work only with coordinates with a precision under 'x' meters (your choice for the value of x)

Also don't forget GPS doesn't give you a perfect position, in the best case you are in a 5 meter radius.

Comment: Even if i set the DesiredAccuracy to 10 m it returns me data with horizontal  accuracy more than 10 m. More accurate you go drains the battery..

Comment: Is there a way to find out the source (such as WiFi or GPS) of location data in ios world???

Comment: Yes there is, but this is a question and should be posted as such

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is as GPS works. Accuracy is 3,5m on average, which will be delivered as horicontal Accuracy = 5m, but however this is an estimate, the location may be wrong sometimes 50m.

A consumer device can not do better, centimeter accuracy costs 5000€.

If you want precise location, use only GPS with max acurcay set (Best o BestForNavigation)

Determine if location was delivered by GPS by looking if location has the `speed` attribute set, which is only set when comming from GPS